# Pass Func<> to Select

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm starting with this:

```
query
    .Take(20)
    .Select(item => new
    {
        id = item.SomeField,
        value = item.AnotherField
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .ToDictionary(item => item.id, item => item.value);
```

Now, I want to reuse everything except `SomeField` and `AnotherField`.

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> ReusableMethod<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> query,
    Func<T, int> key,
    Func<T, string> value)
{
    return query
        .Take(20)
        .Select(item => new
        {
            id = key(item),
            value = value(item)
        })
        .AsEnumerable()
        .ToDictionary(item => item.id, item => item.value);
}

query.ReusableMethod(item => item.SomeField, item => item.AnotherField);
```

This works, but the DB query selects more data than required, so I guess that means `ReusableMethod` is using linq-to-objects.

Is it possible to do this while only selecting the required data? I'll add that Func<> is still part magic for me, so I might be missing something obvious.

**Clarification** to avoid confusion: the `Take(20)` is fine, the `Select()` isn't.

Comment: All fields are selected because your `Func` calls cannot be evaluated in SQL, thus the whole object is selected and the function is called on the object.

Comment: @WillemDuncan are you implying it's not possible, or is there a way to get the desired result?

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your funcs with `Expression` and remove the `AsEnumerable` call.

```
 public static Dictionary<int, string> ReusableMethod<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> query,
    Expression<Func<T, int>> key, 
    Expression<Func<T, string>> value)
```

An alternative would be to just return the whole row then. No need for `Expression` in this case.

```
return query
    .Take(20)
    .ToDictionary(key, value);
```

Comment: Any hint on how to use the those in the `Select`? `key.Compile()(item)` puts me back to square one.

Comment: I don't know the correct syntax then. Wrapping them in `Expression` isn't enough.

Comment: @Stijn alternative solution posted.

Comment: Alternative works but indeed it returns the whole row, which I am trying to avoid. I appreciate the effort though.

Comment: what's so bad about returning the whole row?

Comment: The database I'm working with has some large tables, the largest being nearly 100 columns including Text columns. It's bad for the same reasons `select *` is bad.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had the same problem and here is what I did:

1. You have some DbEntity (generated by LINQ to EF,SQL), but you want to query only some fields (I did this to save network bandwidth). You have to create class derived from DbEntity, beacuse you cant create anonyous types in Expression trees and you can not create new instance of DbEntity in select statement. (No need to add any fields, properties etc.)

   public class LocalEntity : DbEntity {}
2. You need to define a method to generate your select expression tree. It should look like this. This will generate expression tree similar to this: .Select(db => new LocalEntity() { Property1 = db.Property1, Proeprty2 = db.Property2})

   ```
   protected Expression<Func<DbEntity, LocalEntity>> getSelectExpression()
   {
       ParameterExpression paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DbEntity), "dbRecord");
       var selectLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<DbEntity, LocalEntity>>(
                           Expression.MemberInit(
                               Expression.New(typeof(LocalEntity)),
                               Expression.Bind(typeof(LocalEntity).GetProperty("DbEntityFieldName"), Expression.Property(paramExpr, "DbEntityFieldName"),
                               ....
                               ))
                           ),
                           paramExpr);

       return selectLambda;
   }
   ```
3. Use it like this:

   query.Select(getSelectExpression()).ToDictionary();

Consider this more as pseudo-code than C# code, as I had to simplify it a lot and I can´t test it, but if oyu make it work, it will transfer from DB only fields you define in getSelectedExpression, not the whole row.